# specify python.h dependency in pyproject.toml

Tags: python-3.x, tox, pyproject.toml

I'm setting up a `pyproject.toml` file and preparing `tox` based testing. On installation of a dependency I'm running into

```
  ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include <Python.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
```

A few lines below it is suggested:

```
You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
  If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
  required for the build and try again.
```

But, is that really the way to go with tox to install binary packages? Can I instead somehow reference my local `python.h`?

Comment: Installing the binary is the much easier route.  Why do you want to build from source?

Comment: Well, it was mostly curiosity. But after giving it some thought I come to the conclusion that also for reproducible builds and no host contamination it makes total sense to use binaries.